# Remove Punctuation When Checking for Duplicate Titled Questions

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, asking-questions, title

I recently saw a question titled "[Jquery vs Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995470/jquery-vs-javascript)" (10k+ users only). I thought, "surely someone has asked this question before", and began looking for a duplicate. [What I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340412/jquery-vs-javascript) is a question with the exact same title, just with a little different punctuation and casing. It was "Jquery vs Javascript" and "jQuery vs. Javascript?". The only difference being the `.`, `?`, and the casing.

Since we now [disallow questions with duplicate titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106796/155292), I propose that when checking for questions with duplicate names, certain punctuation be striped out to prevent the duplicate from occurring in the first place.

As pointed out in the comments, if isn't already, white-space and non-printable characters may want to be removed for duplicate detection as well.

Comment: You might want to add whitespace/non-printing-characters to this request as well, although stripping non-printing-characters prior to title comparison would prevent "those in the know" from getting around the restriction if needed.

Comment: @cdeszaq I thought about it, but my concern is I don't want the duplicate question block to be too aggressive. That's probably why it doesn't check for these things already. However, I think a small subset of punctuation that is used in English grammar (like commas and periods) would be good to strip. Other punctuation like ^ or * are usually more technical, which could be a very similar titled question, but not the same.

Comment: And automatically close and delete [some patterns](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mx2u1.png)... ;-)

Comment: @Arjan Wow, for real. Sometimes I think all questions should be closed at time of posting, and have to be voted open. :S

Comment: @IuliusCæsar, how about [these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+combine+two+queries)...

Comment: Err, are you expecting more edits? See also [When is “EDIT”/“UPDATE” appropriate in a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post/)

Comment: @Arjan I wasn't ruling out the possibly. Thanks, I'll remove it.

Comment: Why stop at closed, @IuliusCæsar? Start all questions off __deleted__ so they have to be approved by 10kers or mods to be seen! (Note to self: revisit this comment when balpha solicits suggestions for April Fools' Day 2013.)

Comment: Child's play, @Pop. We should _wipe the SE hard drives_ every time a question is submitted.

Comment: Now we're making progress, @IuliusCæsar... but perhaps we should burn the entire data center from orbit on submit. Just to be sure.

Comment: @PopularDemand - You may want to do it on keydown as well, since you wouldn't want any unapproved characters getting through.

Comment: That may not be thorough enough, @Popular; I suggest releasing nanites to dismantle the planet the next time stackoverflow.com recieves a SYN.

Comment: If it's thoroughness you're after, @IuliusCæsar, there's always the option of sending a notification to the global inbox of whoever is running the simulation that we call the universe. In that notification, we could request that he perform a backup and reboot/reload.

Comment: Perfect, @Pop! (As long as that entity does not then try to post a question on SU about how to do that... "Getting error trying to reboot my Universix box -- URGENT!!")

Comment: Highly related, if not duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145866/179419

Comment: I noticed something just like this, except weirder. Two questions appeared to have the exact same title. Upon closer inspection, the original had straight quotes (which are displayed as curly quotes when the question is rendered) and the [duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/488420/191178) straight up used curly quotes.