# How did this user pass the quality filter by using the same title twice?

Tags: bug, edits, asking-questions, title, quality-filter

Just see these two questions:

First: [How to retrieve yahoo contact in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16371176/1369235)
and
Second: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16373262/1369235

A same user asked two questions with the same title.

Title of both questions (before the [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16373262/1)):

> 1. How to retrieve yahoo contact in Android?
> 2. How to retrieve yahoo contact in Android ?

<sub>(only difference is that space between Android and ?).</sub>

A user tried to improve the post (only body and **not** title) but [he got this error message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179019/187824):

> [image]

If someone get this error while editing a question then how can a user ask a question with the same title? (In other words if space difference is not considered while editing then why it is considered while asking?)

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145866/179419, my answer basically demonstrates this. A simple win is to lower case everything and strip out punctuation when making thw check.