# Don't allow questions that have the same title but different punctuation such as a question mark or hyphen

Tags: feature-request, title, quality-filter

I was on Music, and I saw this question title:

[image: The title is "What is Concert Pitch" with a capital C in concert, a capital P in pitch, and no question mark]

I found a question it is apparently a duplicate of with this title:

[image: The title is "What is concert pitch?" with concert and pitch not capitalized and a question mark]

If I were to ask a question called "What is concert pitch?" the system would stop me, as it would have the same title as another—I assume to avoid some obvious duplicates. However, apparently because of the lack of a question mark ([but not the difference in capitalization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpIey.png)), the newer question was able to be titled that.

**If a question has a question mark or other punctuation as the only difference between its title and another, it should be treated as the same question title and not be allowed.** This could stop things like if I tried to ask a question called "How do you conjugate the first-person imperative?" on Spanish and then change it to "How do you conjugate the first person imperative" (which [is allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1kYq.png)) to get it through, making an dupe and filling the review queues.

Comment: Disagreed because I think there could be non-dupe questions with the same title (for instance with names but different persons; "What did John Smith die of?"). However, I think it could be relevant to throw an additional "WAIT! We found the exact same question title [here]! Please make sure they're different different​ questions" popup before the actual asking, on top of the existing "similar questions" dropdown.

Comment: Hum, this is apparently already done? [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104546/398063) is marked as [status-completed] but was not given a staff answer explaining the eventual behaviour.

Comment: [It wasn't done a year after that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127986/179419) @Jenayah, and [the duplication filter is also case sensitive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/265749/179419).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The title word filter is one of the worst ideas ever implemented on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so?rq=1#comment293220_112944) - While I support the idea, it is a duplicate.