# My Stack Overflow account and all entries of the last days are gone. What happened?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

My Stack Overflow account and all my answers of the last days are gone. Yesterday everything was o.k. and I didn't get a notification that something happened.

E.g. my answer for [A simple example for implementing OAuth2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254876/a-simple-example-for-implementing-oauth2-0)

What did I do wrong?

---

My comments to current state of discussion (Apr 7, 2012):

**Sorry for submitting in the wrong way. This was the root cause for deleting my account.**

A further discussion if it was „just blatant promotion“ or my personal laziness makes no sense. There is no excuse to break a rule. Even if you are not aware of it (*[Ignorantia juris non excusat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignorantia_juris_non_excusat)*).

I'm just surprised and shocked that my account and postings have been deleted without any warning. Maybe this practice is somewhere written down, but it is not a good practice. We are all humans and we just do mistakes. Sometimes we get guilty for the things we do and sometimes for the things we don't do.

Dear reader, **Also your account can be deleted and your work will be away - without any warning!'** This gives me a very uncertain feeling. Stack Overflow would be well advised to send at least one e-mail with “He warning, don't do this again or you are out here!”. Hey, maybe You are the next.

This is a grate site! Thank to all the submitters for good questions and answers. I just wanted to give something back to the community. Many thank to all of you.

Comment: Your current account [is brand new](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1318748/user1318748). To what earlier account are you referring?

Comment: I suppose you're the owner of the _cough_ "answer" to that question that was deleted. That reads more like an ad for some project you are participating in than an answer. If all your other "answers" were like that, that account was apparently treated as a spam account and removed.

Comment: @Arjan - The account for user1288938 got deleted 9 hours ago.

Comment: Seems you're right, @Jeff. If Uphill referred to the correct user, then [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350814/accessing-the-java-call-stack/9844728#9844728) feels like a plug for a blog too.

Comment: What can I do now?

Comment: Stop spamming. That's what you can do.

Comment: Re your edit: Do you really expect that we notify every spammer "Hey, you're spamming, we may delete your stuff"? If there's any indication that benefit of the doubt may be appropriate, it's usually given; deletion only happens in the most obvious case. Blaming targetted undisclosed astroturfing on "laziness" is ridiculous. I suggest that we just leave this thing behing us, and you, knowing what you learned here, start over again with your fresh account.

Comment: The warning is [in the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion), I'd say. And assuming you're here to stay: please note that (surely on the regular sites) we don't like edits like you did above. We're not a forum, and adding responses/conclusions to your post above *might* indicate you'd like to use it as such. (Of course, this very Meta site is different in subjects and usage, so maybe you already understood that. See also [When is “EDIT”/“UPDATE” appropriate in a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post). Welcome back!)

Answer (score 21):

Your account was deleted (and the answers with it) as a spammer account. Which is precisely what it was.

In total, you posted 12 "answers", seven of which yesterday alone.

None of them actually were answers, instead they were teasers (yes, sometimes even including "... read more"!) for posts *on your blog*.

At no point did you disclose that you were linking to your own stuff.

Finally, from the looks of it, you chose the questions to "answer" from a search for keywords  that matched the article you wanted to promote, not because you found a question and thought "Hey, I can help this guy".

Sorry, but posting behavior can't get much more spammy than that, so it's no wonder that a moderator deleted that user account.

Comment: So, I understand what happened. I tried to give useful hint or comments. What I learned is, that it is better to copy the interesting  content directly into the answer and not to just put a link to another page in. I've been to lazily. This was my fault.

Comment: That might indeed be one of the reasons, @user, see [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) (However, I can't tell how relevant your answers would have been if more complete.)

Comment: @user you seem to have not understood his point about selectively answering questions which could be used to advertise your blog. Copypasting would be bad as well--since you'd link to your blog. Even if you mention that the entry is from your blog, doing it seven times in one day is just blatant promotion.

Comment: @user I've seen plenty of users quoting from their blogs and/or giving 'additional reading' links to their blogs, but they (1) mention that it's their blog; (2) don't do it often.