# Handling deceptive "Edit:" in unedited post

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, edits

I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11979112/1188942), in which the asker states their question, then writes:

> EDIT:
>
> Figured this out!

The problem, however, is **they never edited the question**. This seems to be intentionally deceptive, although I suppose they could claim they *did* edit the post -- in the original "Ask Question" box. But they were editing/creating the question the whole time, so that explanation seems shaky at best.

The OP answered their own question approximately 22 seconds after they posted it. The only possible reason for this that I can think of is they were either not aware of the "Answer your own question" option or believed there was a certain taboo assosciated with it.

Anyway, how should I handle this? Should I:

1. Edit out their "edit?"
2. Flag the question and explain the reason for flagging?
3. Leave it be?

To address the five-minute leeway period:

I viewed their question after 17 seconds, and the edit was there. 5 seconds later, their answer popped up. I doubt they solved their question, submitted their edit, and then submitted their answer in 22 seconds.

Comment: It's more of a P.S. than Edit i suppose...

Comment: If they edited it within a few minutes of posting it, it won't show in the edit log.

Answer (score 10):

Leave it be.

You have leeway before it starts showing that you edited the post (five minutes?) and it's not unusual that talking to the duck solves the problem.

Even if it was deliberate, so what?

Comment: Well, if the OP has figured out the issue within minutes of posting the question it's probably a good candidate to Close as "Too Localized".

Comment: @TartLevee: That does not follow at all.

Comment: Perhaps, but I viewed their question after 17 seconds, and the edit was there. Five seconds later, their answer popped up. I doubt they solved their question, submitted their edit, and then submitted their answer in 22 seconds.

Comment: @jeff So the last sentence comes in to play--so what? What's to be gained by pursuing it?

Comment: There's nothing monumental to be gained from pursuing justice, I admit, but I don't believe we should allow that kind of dishonesty here.

Comment: @Jeff *What* kind? You already know you can answer your own questions. 17 seconds doesn't even give you enough time to waste on your own answer. I fail to see any meaningful issue here.

Comment: The kind where you claim to have edited an unedited post.

Comment: @jeff ... So flag it, comment, and post on meta. Geez.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really think there's significant or troublesome "deception" here, but I do think that you should remove that last section. It's redundant, since we can all see that the asker figured it out -- e has posted an answer -- and ["EDIT:" is very rarely, if ever, necessary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post).