# For educational reasons - please explain why I got upvoted and downvoted in this specific question

Tags: discussion, down-votes, specific-question, up-votes

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168313/unable-to-access-center-property-of-uiview-from-outside-the-class) question.
At the beginning only the part before "EDIT" appeared.
I immediately got 3 upvotes on the question. Why? I don't believe it was really helpful to anyone but me. Is it because it was phrased accordingly to the rules ?

Later, two things happened: I edited the question by adding the real code to help people helping me. Shortly after I found out the problem myself and it was somewhere else - the bug was not related to the code I suspected. So I posted my own answer explaining what the problem was. I +1ed the answers which are correct but did not help me solving the problem since they just could not.

At that time I got heavily downvoted and I don't understand why. I don't have the rights to see who downvoted and ask why.

I am not questioning the downvotes, I only want to understand what I did wrong

Comment: I only see one downvote on that question, am I missing something?

Comment: `I dont have the rights to see who downvoted and ask why` No one can see who downvoted, voting (up & down) is anonymous.

Comment: I don't think you got heavily downvoted - you only got -1, but people probably retract their upvote after they see that the answer is not derivable from the question you asked and wasted their time.

Comment: I can't tell you if this is the reason or not, but the lack of good file naming conventions makes this a monster to understand. Now, you're intimately familiar enough with the code that B.m and C.m and A.m all make sense to you, but not to people trying to help you who have never ever seen your code before.... just something to think about....

Comment: @nhahtdh - I see -7 in my reputation with two events.

Comment: @jmort253 - actaully, I tried to simplify the files names so it is easier to follow. My actual file names are long :). But I get your point. thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Interesting perspective though. I actually think more meaningful names would be better than generic letters. It's good you're thinking of making your questions readable though. :)

Comment: @LouisShraga: 1 downvote and 1 unupvote.

Comment: As an aside: [When is “EDIT”/“UPDATE” appropriate in a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post) and the [difference between a line break and a paragraph](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635).

Answer (score 10):

> I immediately got 3 upvotes on the question. Why? I dont believe it was really helpful to anyone but me. Is it because it was phrased accordingly to the rules ?

Votes are anonymous, there is no way to tell who cast them or why.

However, I'll hazard a guess as to where the upvotes came from. There is a new tool accessible to users with more than 2000 reputation points, the "review queue". One of the possible actions in this tool is to upvote. When you have made a certain number of reviews (Including upvotes), you stand to earn a gold badge.

Apparently, there are some users who will just click through lots of questions and upvote everything they see to get the badge, regardless of quality. Your question *may* have got three upvotes because of this. This is a problem for the site overall, and I expect it will be fixed eventually.

The downvote *may* have been to cancel those upvotes out. I do that occasionally when I see a lot of clearly misguided upvotes piling up on a question. However, the voter may also have had issues with your post's quality - I can't judge that as I'm not qualified to.