# What should I do if I think a suggested edit is unjustly rejected?

Tags: discussion, edits, review, suggested-edits

Today I was reviewing [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2505010), which according to the provided picture is obviously right, but it got rejected by three reviewers based on the reason

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

What should I do in this case? What I did was I copied the code of the suggested edit and made an edit myself.

Is there another way to make this edit get reviewed again or make it pass the review queue with the original editor as the one who suggested the change (because the original editor was [kind of confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637627/vb-net-doesnt-return-function?noredirect=1#comment25681999_17637627))?

What would be the correct thing to do if you see an edit which is rejected although it is not wrong?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88627/212576

Comment: @hjpotter92: My question was not about what to change in other people's code but what to do when you see an (obviously right) edit being rejected.

Comment: The edit was not correct. Since the OP already has the code, they can copy-paste them to the question. Anyone else editing the code is considered an *incorrect edit*.

Comment: As an aside, I know it wasn't your edit, but you could have taken it out when copying: the *"From the code in the provided picture, you missed this line"* hurts my eyes; see [When is “EDIT”/“UPDATE” appropriate in a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post)

Comment: @hjpotter92: The editor added code the original author did not include although he showed it in the picture, and it belonged to the code for completeness. It should be allowed to make the question more clear by changing the way it is presented (without changing the content), in this case copying from image to text.

Comment: That's an edge case, with 50/50 chances of getting through. As the one who suggest such edit you can try again, risking eventual edit ban, as 2K user you can do exactly what you did: improve the post yourself. We can't "make an edit get reviewed again" or suggest edits with 2K rep.

Comment: I've decided to stop editing for a while.  Reject reasons that are so off-the-wall or rude or unjustified are too discouraging; and the notion of a 'community' should run in both directions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In another case I would have agreed with this rejection.

However in this *specific* case, the image posted by the OP shows the actual code that is used by the OP. And obviously the OP missed the first line when he was typing out the question.

So what the editor did was adding the missing line to make it consistent with the image. **In other words, the editor made the code in the post consistent with the actual code that the OP has**. So I think this suggested edit is correct (despite the misplaced code comment).

The gotcha is that this fact isn't immediately obvious to the reviewers. So it would seem to them as if the editor was trying to add (his own) code to the question which is not acceptable.

To prevent such misunderstanding, always include relevant information in the edit comment (*not* as a comment in the code). For example, in this case

> Added a line to make the code consistent with the actual code that the OP has (see the screenshot posted in the question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNsyq.jpg)

So you did the right thing. But arguably you could've done better by removing the code comment and put in a proper edit comment as described above.

Note: to my limited knowledge, there's no way to get a suggested edit reviewed again after it was rejected, short of asking the editor to re-submit a new suggested edit.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the suggested edit was rejected for the following comment that was added from the user who suggested the edit:

> From the code in the provided picture, you missed this line

You don't edit a post to communicate with the user who wrote the post (whenever it is a question or an answer). The fact the user wrote "you missed" makes clear he was trying to do that.
He should have used a comment; in the case he doesn't have the privilege of commenting on questions written by others, he should not have suggested the edit.

The rejection reason says it: "**This edit is** incorrect or **an attempt to** reply to or **comment on the existing post**."