# Possible issue: Chrome v29 (OS X) currently not showing bold font in post?

Tags: bug, design, google-chrome, fonts

Reference Post: [Does using an unofficial charger negatively affect overall battery lifetime of a GS4?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53195/does-using-an-unofficial-charger-negatively-affect-overall-battery-lifetime-of-a)

[image: Strong not showing as bold]

As of right now (Sep 19, 10:33am EDT) on OS X 10.8.5, Chrome v29.0.1547.65, bold font is not working, for me at least. The post has "Update:" in bold (double asterisk). When I view Chrome Developer Tools, the font has `font-weight:bold` from all.css, but then "user agent stylesheet" overrides it.

**Bold** works here though... so, no idea what the difference is.  I've tried hard-refreshing, but doesn't help.

It's also worth noting that Chrome Developer Tools shows the opposite for css rules on this page -- where the "user agent stylesheet" is crossed out and the `font-weight:fold` from all.css is not.  Perhaps the Android SE site's custom style sheet has a missing `!important` or something?

Comment: So you didn't setup a user stylesheet?

Comment: No custom stylesheets from me.

Comment: As an aside, I feel [using **Update:** is bad](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post).

Comment: Note that `<strong>` (as used by SE) and `<b>` are not the same, and might indeed have a totally different design/rendering. (That said, the CSS *does* indeed specify `font-weight: bold;`.)

Comment: Arjan -- thanks. I wasn't aware of this shared belief, so will be changing my ways.

Comment: (Well, as for using Edit/Update: 23 people agreed, 2 disagreed, from those who voted. It's not a golden rule, of course.)

Comment: Renders fine on my Chrome, but I'm running Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I see the same on my Mac, where Chrome 29 seems to use DroidSansRegular out of the following:

```css
font-family: 
  Roboto, 'Droid San', 'DroidSansRegular', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
```

This somehow does not *really* show bold (it seems to show some extra spacing). Removing that font from the CSS makes Chrome use Helvetica Neue and show bold just fine.

This is a web font that is downloaded by the browser:

```css
@font-face{
  font-family: 'DroidSansRegular'; 
  src: url('img/droidsans-webfont.eot'); 
  src: url('img/droidsans-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
    url('img/droidsans-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('img/droidsans-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('img/droidsans-webfont.svg#webfontDqsfQWaa') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal; 
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Maybe the `font-weight: normal;` makes Chrome fail to find it when bold is needed?

Also, it renders fine in my Firefox and Safari. Maybe those are always using Helvetica Neue, or make a different choice as for the downloaded format. Or simply have no problem with bolding the web font.